# How to integrate Shiny mode into Ace editor in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ace-editor, shiny

I was able to integrate the shinyAce app up and running using the link given here in a R environment (https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce)

But I would want to integrate shinyAce with my Rails app. How should I go about approaching this